# Insert a dynamic component as child of a container in the DOM angular2

Tags: angular

In my project, I want to insert component dynamically as a child of parent container. Here is the code

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
  <ng-container>
  <child1></child1>
<button (click)="me()">me</button>
  </ng-container>

  `
})
export class ParentComponent {

  componentRef:any;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  me() {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(Child2Component);
    this.componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
    // this.componentRef._component.role = role;
    this.componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

In the above code, there is `parent` component that by default contains `child1` component. There is a button that inserts another component(`child2`). But this is inserted as a sibling of the parent component.

```
<parent>
  <child1></child1>
</parent>
<child2></child2>
```

I want to insert it as a child of the parent component.

```
<parent>
  <child1></child1>
  <child2></child2>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a selector to your container

```
<ng-container #selector> // <-- add selector tag here
  <child1></child1>
  <button (click)="me()">me</button>
</ng-container>
```

then you can use it as a field instead of `ViewContainerRef`

```
@ViewChild('selector', {read: ViewContainerRef}) selector;
```

---

```
this.componentRef = this.selector.createComponent(factory);
```

Comment: in this case, I can insert only one child, right? what if i have to insert multiple  children?

Comment: @SunilGarg I don't know what you mean by that but everytime you click on `me()`, it will append a new component. You can easily check this with a flag though.

Comment: thanks!! this is working fine. can I use `@input` and `@output` properties to communicate with the parent?

Comment: @SunilGarg I don't think so. You need to use a shared service among those components.

Answer (score 4):

Dynamic components are always added as sibling of the `ViewContainerRef`. If you want it as child, add a child element and acquire the `ViewContainerRef` of this element to make the dynamic component a sibling of this one.

Comment: can you please give me a demo?

Comment: Supose you want to add a component that uses  `<tr>` element:
`<tbody> 
   <ng-container #trContainer></ng-container> 
</tbody>`
In **ts** code you do: `@ViewChild('trContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) trContainer;`